# How to Concat two maps in Elixir

Tags: maps, elixir

I have two maps in Elixir:

```elixir
mapA = %{"test1" => "result1"}
mapB = %{"test2" => "result2"}
```

I want my output to look like this:

```elixir
[%{"test1" => "result1"}, %{"test2" => "result2"}]
```

Comment: `mapC = [mapA] ++ [mapB]`

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to put them in a [list](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html), like your example:

```elixir
[mapA, mapB]
[%{"test1" => "result1"}, %{"test2" => "result2"}]
```

If what you actually meant is that you wanted to [`merge`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/2) the maps:

```elixir
Map.merge(mapA, mapB)
%{"test1" => "result1", "test2" => "result2"}
```